# Why don't I need to specify arguments to tkinter command= when using lambda

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

How come when linking a method to a tkinter button using `command=` and a lambda function (since I'm passing variables), I don't have to put those as arguments in the lambda function .... for example, in normal code, I would write:

```
def basicPrint(a,b): print(a+b)
```

as a lambda, I would use:

```
basicPrint = lambda a,b: print(a+b)
```

However, when it's used in a tkinter button I have to put:

```
command=lambda: self.basicPrint(a,b))
```

i.e., I have to omit the a,b after the word lambda, but this would kick up an error when called in 'normal' code:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

So why is it different in the tkinter case? Something to do with "self" in there?

Comment: Presumably because a and b are being closed over, not passed in when the lambda is invoked. It's certainly not generally the case that a function you call from within another function must have the same parameters as the caller, why would that be the case here?

Comment: You omit `a, b` for command, because the command function does not expect any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`command` specifies a *callback*, which is a function you write that a framework will call. The framework will specify the signature of the function, which your function *must* conform to, because the the calling code in the framework is written to call your function in a fixed way. In this specific case, there is no way for you to tell `tkinter` what values to pass to your function. So it won't pass any. This would cause a runtime error, and to avoid that, `tkinter` checks the signature of your function beforehand and complains if the signature does not follow the documented specification. So you have written a function  that meets `tkinter`'s specification but relies on the presence of global variables to work.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply how tkinter is designed to work. A function bound to an event must accept a single argument. That argument is an object that describes the event. When you provide a function to `command`, that function must be callable without any arguments.

Whether you use `lambda`, `functools.partial`, or simply provide a reference to a standard function, those rules must be followed.